Unable to get template types. Failed to load configuration from file 'D:\apps\Tridion\Config\addonsSettings.json'
Getting the below error while retreiving an item from Tridion using core services.
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Unable to get template types.
Failed to load configuration from file 'D:\apps\Tridion\Config\addonsSettings.json'.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Welcome to tridion stackexchange. Could you please update and provide trace logs details of the error. maybe you can find it in the event viewer in the Tridion Sites installed server.

Error looks System.Text.Json assemply version is missing, could be pre-requisites are not installed. also update provide details of which version of tridion sites etc

Which version of Tridion Sites are you using?  Problem is most likely that you have System.Text.Json in your GAC, but not version 6.0.0.0 (which is referenced by other assemblies).  We see such problems quite often during development, but they should not occur on a released versions.

@RickPannekoek, we are using Sites10 version. Both in our code and in GAC we are using System.Text.Json 6.0.121..version. But error message says that not able to find "6.0.0.0". How can we find that where this 6.0.0.0 version file is being referred? Could you please help me on this.Pannekoek

Given the error message, the reference seems to be in the Addons SDK/Client.  You can use MS's Assembly Binding Log Viewer (aka Fusion Log Viewer) to get more info about assembly binding problems in general: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

I have setup the fusion log viewer, no log related to this dll is not recorded. But when i check in registry editor, particular dll is present since i have added to GAC. Can anyone please help me with next steps?

This is not an Answer. Please update the original Question with more details instead.
